# How do I merge two SVN branches?

Tags: svn, merge

I have two SVN branches checked out, "b1" and "b2". I would like to merge all of my commits from the "b1" branch onto the "b2" branch. I have tried something like

```
svn merge -r HEAD:HEAD b1 b2
```

but it does nothing. I am sure I have this command wrong, but I can't find good documentation on it. I would like to do this on the client side and not create a third branch.

I am using SVN 1.4.4 which doesn't support the reintegrate option.

How can I do it?

Comment: Just type "svn help merge" to get help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your problem is with the `-r` flag. You have to specify a *range* of revisions. So for example:

```
svn merge -r 13:HEAD b1 b2
```

To figure out the correct revision number you can do:

```
svn log --stop-on-copy b1
```

`log` will then only list commits which happened on `b1`. The smallest revision number you'll see will be your pick.

I've never used this form though. I always ensured that I was actively **on** branch `b2`, and then did:

```
svn merge -r 13:HEAD url://to/branch/b1
```

Answer (score 7):

From the [reference page for svn merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.merge.html) in [the Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html):

```
$ svn merge --reintegrate \
            http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-calc-branch
--- Merging differences between repository URLs into '.':
U    button.c
U    integer.c
U    Makefile
 U   .

$ # build, test, verify, ...

$ svn commit -m "Merge my-calc-branch back into trunk!"
Sending        .
Sending        button.c
Sending        integer.c
Sending        Makefile
Transmitting file data ..
Committed revision 391.
```

**Edit**:
OK, so you're using an old version of Subversion.  In that case, see [Merging a Whole Branch to Another](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.branchmerge.commonuses.html#svn.branchmerge.commonuses.wholebr) in [version 1.4 of the book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/).

Comment: i can't find good documentation on what exactly reintegrate does.  i am merging one branch to another, not one branch to the trunk. and as specified in the question, this will be done on 2 working copies of the branches (think local directories and not svn server URL's).  can you update your answer to reflect these concerns?

Comment: also i have svn version 1.4.4 which doesn't seem to support the reintegrate option.  since that seems to be a shortcut for a longer command, i would appreciate the longer version.  thanks!