# Merge two branches svn Xcode?

Tags: xcode, svn

When I try to merge two branches in Xcode the current branch is null, merge  dialog text as the following :
choose the branch to merge into the current branch
the current branch of your working copy is "(null)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you want is directly merge two existing branch into a new working copy and create a third merged branch. Is that what you are looking for ?

Anyway this doesn't work like that. First you have to run the command (or call the dialog) from a working copy. In other words you have to checkout a first branch or trunk revision.

Then you may be interrested by the so called "2-URL merge", see `svn help merge` for full details.

> ```
>    - 2-URL Merge Example -
>
>  Two features have been developed on separate branches called 'foo' and
>  'bar'. It has since become clear that 'bar' should be combined with
>  the 'foo' branch for further development before reintegration.
>
>  Although both feature branches originate from trunk, they are not
>  directly related -- one is not a direct copy of the other. A 2-URL
>  merge is necessary.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few sources you can check out, I don't know if they will help out:

[How do I merge two SVN branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371438/how-do-i-merge-two-svn-branches)

http://blog.e-shell.org/192

and

http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/58122/It-s-Time-to-Fix-Subversion-Merge.aspx

Personally, I am not a big fan of SVN anymore, but I guess it is a matter of preference.